# How do I add values to a variable based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable @tableset. These should contain tables whose count is not 0. For e.g.

```
if @count1 <> 0 then @tableset = @table1

else if @count1 = 0 and @count2 <> 0 then @tablset = @table2

else if @count1 = 0 and @count2 = 0 then @tableset = @table1 + @table2

where count1 is the count of table1
count2 is the count of table2
```

Instead of writing multiple if conditions, I would like to make this happen in a code-efficient manner so that in future if the number of tables increase, it is easier to scale this query.

This is a sample code that I have written for SQL Server:

```
IF @count1 = 0 and @count2 = 0 and @count3 = 0 and @count4 =0 and @count5 = 0 
set @tableset=@table1   

IF @count1 = 0 and @count2 = 0 and @count3 = 0 and @count4 =0 and @count5 = 0 
set @tableset=@table1
```

Thus I need to write a stored proc with the following logic:

```
if @count1 <> 0 then @tableset = @table1
     else if @count1 = 0 and @count2 <> 0 then @tablset = @table2
    else if @count1 = 0 and @count2 = 0 then @tableset = @table1 + @table2
```

Comment: I think you don't understand how table variables work. It isn't like a string in C# where you can just add stuff together. These are tables and have to be treated like tables.

Comment: To expand on what @SeanLange wrote: please explain how you are using / planning to use `@tableset` variable after you have set the value to it.

Comment: These are actually HTML tables embedded into my SQL Server Stored Procs. Each table has a HTML code. When that results of the sql used inside the HTML table is 0, I will not email the contents of that particular table to user. So I create a variable `@tableset` to hold whichever table is containing count = 0. Like this:
    `set  @tablelist=@tableHTML1+@tableHTML2+@tableHTML3`
       This variable is used in sp_send_dbmail as the email body.      Like this: `@body = @tablelist`

Each count is the result of a SQL and corresponding table is added based on the count to the table list.

Comment: OK so it seems that your variable names are just confusing and these are actually scalar values. It is not at all clear what you want accomplish here. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.